# Wordpress REST API 404

Tags: 404-error, api

I have installed WP 4.9.5 using nginx and the following plugins:
Gravity Forms (v2.3.1) by rocketgenius
Advanced Custom Fields PRO (v5.6.10) by Elliot Condon
Timber (v1.7.0) by Jared Novack + Upstatement
WooCommerce Additional Variation Images (v1.7.12) by WooCommerce
WooCommerce (v3.3.5) by Automattic

For some reason i cannot understand REST api calls are not working and return 404 error. I am trying the simplest GET without requiring authentication

http://domain.test/wp-json/wc/v2/

any help appreciated!

Comment: DId you turn on pretty permalinks? Without rewrite rules the REST API doesn't work

Comment: Yes! Permalinks are enabled. I have also tried to make calls using query string parameter (without permalinks) with no success.

Comment: Have you contacted the support routes for those plugins?

Comment: I have this same issue. I'm on an Ubuntu-server, but I've simply pointed my host-file to point to the IP. I must admit I'm not 100% sure how the restful API works, if that has any effect or not. I'm on WP version 4.9.8, - and have the problem when I activate the Gutenberg-plugin.

Comment: Same issue in 2019.  They see this error beeing up for years, why the heck don't they do anything, like improve debugging for this case... noobs.

Answer (score 3):

I commented this, for my situation:

> I have this same issue. I'm on an Ubuntu-server, but I've simply
>   pointed my host-file to point to the IP. I must admit I'm not 100%
>   sure how the restful API works, if that has any effect or not. I'm on
>   WP version 4.9.8, - and have the problem when I activate the
>   Gutenberg-plugin.

It seems that my .htaccess-file wasn't writable (I saw that it wasn't in the bottom of the 'Permalinks'-page, where it said that it was a bit sad). When I added the .htaccess-file manually and uploaded it, with below-written content, then it started worked.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```